Understanding Riccati's differential equation
I wanted to understand the below generalized Riccati's differential equation,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ax^n+by^2$$
which is solvable by algebraic, exponential, and logarithmic functions only when $n=\frac{-4m}{2m\pm1},  m= 0, 1, 2,\cdots\implies n = 0,-\frac{4}{3},-4,-\frac{8}{3},-\frac{8}{5},\cdots$

My original question was
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x^2+5y^2.$$
When I tried to compare with the above reference, It clearly does not match a $n$ value which allows me to solve using algebraic, exponential, and logarithmic functions.
So on running this differential equation through WA, I got the result in Bessel function.
Is there any general solution to that above general differential equation in terms of Bessel function?
Edit - Just found this, but there’s no analytic solution there as well, except the hint given as $x=z^a$ transformation to be used in the above equation to convert it to another Bessel DE which I do not understand how, I have tried quite a lot around that substitution but not able to map it to anything.
Moreover, I’m unable to find any source which discusses that specific differential equation anywhere, which makes me skeptical of any general solution’s existence.
References I found (but finding it hard to use it all) - 1, 2, 3
Edit - This is the solution WA gives;
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{30}x^2\left(-c_1J_{-\frac{5}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)+c_1J_{\frac{3}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)-2J_{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)\right)-c_1J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)}{10x\left(c_1J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)+J_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}x^2\right)\right)}$$
My question is how is this above result computed analytically?

The statement at the beginning of the question isn't quite right: The differential equation $y' = ax^n + by^2$ can also be solved in terms of algebraic, exponential, and logarithmic functions when $n = -2$, which corresponds to the limiting case $m \to \pm \infty$ in the given parameterization of special values. This follows immediately from the fact that the second-order linear equation corresponding to the Riccati equation is in that case a Cauchy–Euler equation; see my answer for more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ax^n+by^2$$
A usual way to solve the Riccati ODEs which is a first order non-linear ODE is to transform it into a second order linear ODE because a linear ODE is generaly simpler to solve that a non-linear ODE even if the order is higher.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html , Eqs. $(4)$ , $(5)$.
$$y=-\frac{u'}{bu}\quad\implies\quad u''+abx^nu=0$$
The transformed equation is a linear ODE of Bessel kind.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html , Eqs. $(6)$ , $(7)$.
$$u=c_1x^{1/2}J_{1/(n+2)}\left(\frac{2ab}{n+2}x^{(n+2)/2} \right)+
c_1x^{1/2}J_{-1/(n+2)}\left(\frac{2ab}{n+2}x^{(n+2)/2} \right)\quad;\quad n\neq -2$$
Then $y=-\frac{u'}{bu}$ leads to the solution in terms of Bessel functions.
In case of $n=-2$ the solution reduces to elementary functions.

Provided $b \neq 0$ applying the standard substitution, $$y = -\frac1b \frac{u'}u ,$$ transforms the Riccati equation into a second-order linear o.d.e.,
$$u'' + a b x^n u = 0 .$$ (If $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, the equation in $y$ is separable and straightforward to integrate, so we henceforth assume $a b \neq 0$.) Changing variables via $u = \sqrt x v$ transforms the equation to
$$x^2 v'' + x v' + \left(a b x^{2 + n} - \frac14\right) v = 0 .$$
If $n \neq -2$ and $a b > 0$ (as is the case for the sample equation in the question statement), then substituting $t = \frac{2 \sqrt{a b}}{2 + n} x^\frac{2 + n}{2}$ transforms the equation to the Bessel differential equation,
$$t^2 v'' + t v' + (t^2 - \alpha^2) v = 0, \qquad \textrm{where} \quad \alpha := \frac{1}{2 + n},$$
whose solution space is spanned by $J_\alpha, Y_\alpha$, respectively the Bessel Functions of the First and Second Kinds. When $\alpha \not\in \Bbb Z$ (which is the case for the example equation, where $n = 2$, so that $\alpha = \frac14$), the solution space is spanned by $J_\alpha, J_{-\alpha}$, and so the general solution is
$$v(t) = A J_\alpha(t) + B J_{-\alpha}(t) , \qquad A, B \in \Bbb R .$$
Backsubstituting and using the derivative identity $J_\alpha'(t) = - J_{1 + \alpha}(t) + \frac\alpha t J_\alpha(t)$ gives the general solution
$$\boxed{y(x) = \sqrt{\frac ab} x^{\frac n2} \cdot \frac{-A J_{\frac 1{2 + n} - 1}\left(\frac 2{2 + n} \sqrt{a b} x^{\frac {n + 2} 2}\right) + B J_{1 - \frac 1{2 + n}}\left(\frac 2{2 + n} \sqrt{a b} x^{\frac {n + 2} 2}\right)}{A J_{\frac 1{2 + n}}\left(\frac 2{2 + n} \sqrt{a b} x^{\frac {n + 2} 2}\right) + B J_{-\frac 1{2 + n}}\left(\frac 2{2 + n} \sqrt{a b} x^{\frac {n + 2} 2}\right)}} .$$
When $\alpha \in \Bbb Z$, $\{J_\alpha, J_{-\alpha}\}$ is linearly dependent and so does not span the solution spaced, but we can write a similar expression for the general solution in terms of $J_\alpha, Y_\alpha$ that also applies to that case.
The case $n \neq -2$, $a b < 0$, is similar, but we instead set $t = \frac{2 \sqrt{-a b}}{2 + n} x^\frac{2 + n}{2}$, which transforms the equation into the Modified Bessel Equation, the solution space for $v(t)$ of which is spanned by $I_\alpha$ and $K_\alpha$, respectively the Modified Bessel Functions of the First and Second Kinds.
In the special case $n = -2$, the equation in $u$ is $x^2 u'' + ab u = 0$, which is a Cauchy–Euler equation; so, it has an elementary general solution, and the qualitative behavior of the solution set depends on the sign of $a b - \frac14$.
Remark When the parameter $\alpha$ is a half-integer, $J_\alpha, Y_\alpha, I_\alpha, K_\alpha$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. In our solutions this occurs when $\frac1{2 + n} = m + \frac12$, $m \in \Bbb Z$, i.e., when $$\boxed{n = -\frac{4 m}{1 + 2 m}} .$$ The case $n = -2$ corresponds to the limiting case $m \to \pm \infty$.
